# Android error TYPE_WIFI canot be resolved or is not a field?

Tags: android, android-wifi

```
  mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

`TYPE_WIFI` canot be resolved or is not a field

i get this error can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: is that your mWifi is an NetworkInfo.

Comment: plz add your Code , so we can see the imports , because it should works , i've tried it right now and it works for me

Comment: Did you import the right `ConnectivityManager` class?

Comment: NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

Comment: import android.net.ConnectivityManager; that was the errot thanks...

Comment: One tip if you are working with Eclipse ; use Ctrl + Space to complete the code , and the Ctrl + Shift + O , to import all missing imports ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Code :

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

i think you have something wrong with your imports , or the variable mWifi should be a `NetworkInfo` type.
i've tried it and it works for me , so you have something wrong just with your imports , and exaclty the `ConnectivityManager`

Comment: i simply need something to check if wifi is disconected

Comment: lol i've just tried it in a project that i'm developing and i've used the name of the Activity , see my edits,  you can use directly this.getSystemService